# Multiple source files to declare inner classes and friendship

Tags: c++

Apologies for my ignorence. I couldn't figure out how to declare body of an inner class using different source files. What i want to achieve is something like this:

source1.h:

```
class A {
    class B;
}
```

source2.h:

```
class B {
//
}
```

source3.cpp: `//Implementation of A`

source4.cpp: `//Implementation of B`

Extra: How friendship between A and B is implied in these kind of declarations?

Comment: I don't see a friend keyword here.

Comment: That is why I said "implied".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will work as long as the definition of `A` does not rely on `B` being a complete type.  (So `A` can contain a reference or pointer to `B`, but not an actual `B` instance because the compiler doesn't know how much space to allocate for `B` until it has seen `B`'s definition.)

In source2.h, you would define the class you declared in source1.h by specifying the scope:

```
class A::B {
    // ...
};
```

In source4.cpp, you would also need to specify scope.  For example, if `B`'s definition declares a no-arg constructor that does nothing:

```
A::B::B() { }
```

It works exactly the same as defining any other class or class members, you just have to prepend `A::` to `B` to let the compiler know where the class is.

I have written a [complete and working example](http://ideone.com/mBvlRh) of this technique.

Regarding "friendship" which I assume means access to class/object members, nested classes have no special access in either direction.<sup>1</sup>  The inner class does not have access to any members of the outer class except those it would normally have access to, and the same rule applies in the other direction.  If you want the inner class to have full access to the members declared in the outer class, it will be necessary to add an explicit friend declaration to the outer class.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is true in C++03 according to the standard (ANSI/ISO C++ 11.8.1: *"The members of a nested class have no special access to
members of an enclosing class..."*) but in C++11 the child class is implicitly a friend of the parent class.  Some compilers act as though there is an implicit friendship declared in the parent class even in C++03, but this behavior cannot be considered portable.  To be safe, explicitly declare the friendship.  This will work equally well on both C++03 and C++11.

Comment: Extremely useful answer! Appreciated. :)

Comment: *nested classes have no special access in either direction*, but they do. The inner class is a member and has access to the outer class´s private members. See [here](http://ideone.com/4Expbg)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas According to the specification, this is not the case.  Many C++ compilers permit this, but it's not standards-compliant until C++11, which formally introduced this behavior.  Portable code can make use of this feature only if it targets C++11.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas To further follow up, this is a [longstanding G++ bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=359). Your example works only because it is being compiled with G++. The relevant C++03 spec section is 11.8.1: *"The members of a nested class have no special access to
members of an enclosing class."* I respectfully request that you withdraw your downvote, or provide additional evidence that this is legal in C++03.

Comment: @cdhowie: I must admit that I tend to think C++11 (only two years old next month) is *the* standard. Yes, in C++03 the nested class has no special access to the outer class.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas As someone who touches a lot of legacy code, C++03 is effectively the standard in my head.  An understandable miscommunication all around -- I should have been clearer in my answer.

Comment: I'm having some trouble when trying to separate your working example into separate files. Could you show how this is done? It seems to me like the includes have to be done in a very specific way for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

When your class A has a member B you need to make the class definition visible before your define class A. You should write:

```
// source1.h
#include "source2.h"
class A {
    class B b;
};
```

When you have only a reference or pointer to an object of class B a forward declaration is suficcient.

```
// source1.h
class B;
class A {
    class B *b;
};
```

With this approach you can define the friendship in the classes.

Further I recommend names for the files that makes the relationship visible.

Comment: Thank you for your attention but class B in my example is not a member. It is another class declared in scope of A in order to be instantiated with `A::` prefix like standard iterators. Sorry for misunderstanding, you still deserved a thumbs up.

Comment: @diegoperini To be sure, you could still use the `A::` prefix even if the class you want to be nested is not declared within `A`.  All you'd have to do is add a typedef in `A`.  For example, you could do `namespace detail { class Foo { ... } }` and then in `A` just have a `typedef detail::Foo B;`.

Comment: Noted. :) Isn't it abusing the common practice (if there is any) to mimic nested scopes via namespaces?